# How can i target specific button's styling with onClick function if i have the same onClick function attached to multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a Trivia app in React, but I'm having trouble changing the background color after the user selected the answer from the given options. I'm trying to do the freeCodeCamp's quiz app with some personal changes.

What it currently does is that it colors every single button green or red depending if the answer was correct or wrong and I would like to target only the specific button that has been clicked with the backgroundColor change and leave the rest as they were.

So, here I have a div where i map out the answer options on different buttons:

```
        <div className='answer-Section'>
          {currentQuestion.answerOptions.map((elem) => (
            <button
              className='answer-Button'
              onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(elem.isCorrect)}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: isAnswered ? bgAnswered : bgNeutral,
              }}
            >
              {elem.answerText}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
```

And here is the onClick event's handler on the mapped buttons:

```
const handleAnswerClick = (isCorrect) => {
setIsAnswered(true)
isCorrect ? setScore(score + 1) : setScore(score)
isCorrect ? setBgAnswered('green') : setBgAnswered('red')
setTimeout(() => findNextQuestion(), 1000)}


const findNextQuestion = () => {
setIsAnswered(false)
const nextQuestion = currentQuestionNumber + 1
if (nextQuestion === questions.length) {
  setShowScore(true)
} else {
  setCurrentQuestionNumber(nextQuestion)
}}
```

Comment: Can the user try and answer multiple times or do they just get one chance?

Comment: No, they can only answer it once.

Comment: Ok I will try and create an answer now

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The simplest would  be to store not just *whether* the question was answered, but which answer was chosen. In the code below, I've also avoided using the `bgAnswered` state variable, instead just computing the desired color inline.

```js
        [answer, setAnswer] = useState();
        //...
        <div className='answer-Section'>
          {currentQuestion.answerOptions.map((elem, i) => (
            <button
              className='answer-Button'
              onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(elem.isCorrect, i)}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: answer === i ? (elem.isCorrect ? 'green' : 'red') : bgNeutral,
              }}
            >
              {elem.answerText}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
```

```js
const handleAnswerClick = (isCorrect, i) => {
  setAnswer(i);
  if (isCorrect) setScore(score + 1);
  setTimeout(() => findNextQuestion(), 1000)
};
```

Another option would be to make `bgAnswered` into an array of values, one for each answer.  But that seems unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks, it works nearly perfectly. Just need to reset the answer state variable, because when you click it it keeps the answer for the next question and highlights if it's true or false.